# iOS7 Blurred Overlay in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I asked this question before and deleted just because 1) it seemed like more work than I wanted to do, and 2) I went about asking my question poorly and it got closed. But, after doing more research, I've decided I will revisit this feature/question/how-to

I am attempting/wanting to create a blurred overlay as seen in the picture below. The obvious FMX.effect to use would be the 'Blur' effect. My question would be: how do I go about rendering the image the overlay would cover, or copying the image in an effective manner to blur for the overlay?

I have thought about using just two of the same bitmap, one for the background and one to blur but then I wouldn't be capture 'blur-ness' of controls or anything else on top of the original background. I also would think that if I were to have the overlay scroll into and out of view, then it would not look/appear as I would want it.

Considering the above, it all leads me to believe I *need* to dynamically capture the background to be blurred as the overlay scrolls/comes into view. How do I go about doing this and capturing current displayed screen content in Delphi XE6?
Not sure where to even start.

*I do not own image* *

[image]

Comment: I've found how to get full screenshots, but can't seem to find anything in FMX regarding selected area screenshots. I think that is all I would need for a simple solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little research on how to capture the parent control background I came up with the following code based on TMagnifierGlass class from FMX (Note that I made this code in XE5, you need to check XE6 compatibility):

```
TGlass = class(TControl)
private
  FBlur: TBlurEffect;
  FParentScreenshotBitmap: TBitmap;
  function GetSoftness: Single;
  procedure SetSoftness(Value: Single);
protected
  procedure Paint; override;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property Softness: Single read GetSoftness write SetSoftness;
end;


{ TGlass }

constructor TGlass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

  inherited Create(AOwner);

  // Create parent background
  FParentScreenshotBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);

  // Create blur
  FBlur := TBlurEffect.Create(nil);
  FBlur.Softness := 0.6;

end;

destructor TGlass.Destroy;
begin

  FBlur.Free;
  FParentScreenshotBitmap.Free;

  inherited Destroy;

end;

function TGlass.GetSoftness: Single;
begin

  Result := FBlur.Softness;

end;

procedure TGlass.SetSoftness(Value: Single);
begin

  FBlur.Softness := Value;

end;

procedure TGlass.Paint;
var
  ParentWidth: Single;
  ParentHeight: Single;

  procedure DefineParentSize;
  begin
    ParentWidth := 0;
    ParentHeight := 0;
    if Parent is TCustomForm then
    begin
      ParentWidth := (Parent as TCustomForm).ClientWidth;
      ParentHeight := (Parent as TCustomForm).ClientHeight;
    end;
    if Parent is TControl then
    begin
      ParentWidth := (Parent as TControl).Width;
      ParentHeight := (Parent as TControl).Height;
    end;
  end;

  function IsBitmapSizeChanged(ABitmap: TBitmap; const ANewWidth, ANewHeight: Single): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := not SameValue(ANewWidth * ABitmap.BitmapScale, ABitmap.Width) or
              not SameValue(ANewHeight * ABitmap.BitmapScale, ABitmap.Height);
  end;

  procedure MakeParentScreenshot;
  var
    Form: TCommonCustomForm;
    Child: TFmxObject;
    ParentControl: TControl;
  begin
    if FParentScreenshotBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
      try
        FDisablePaint := True;
        if Parent is TCommonCustomForm then
        begin
          Form := Parent as TCommonCustomForm;
          for Child in Form.Children do
            if (Child is TControl) and (Child as TControl).Visible then
            begin
              ParentControl := Child as TControl;
              ParentControl.PaintTo(FParentScreenshotBitmap.Canvas, ParentControl.ParentedRect);
            end;
        end
        else
          (Parent as TControl).PaintTo(FParentScreenshotBitmap.Canvas, RectF(0, 0, ParentWidth, ParentHeight));
      finally
        FDisablePaint := False;
        FParentScreenshotBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
      end;
  end;

begin

  // Make screenshot of Parent control
  DefineParentSize;
  if IsBitmapSizeChanged(FParentScreenshotBitmap, ParentWidth, ParentHeight) then
    FParentScreenshotBitmap.SetSize(Round(ParentWidth), Round(ParentHeight));
  MakeParentScreenshot;

  // Apply glass effect
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    FBlur.ProcessEffect(Canvas, FParentScreenshotBitmap, FBlur.Softness);
    Canvas.DrawBitmap(FParentScreenshotBitmap, ParentedRect, LocalRect, 1, TRUE);
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

end;
```

To use, just instantiate TGlass on top of any control, it should make the desired "glassy" effect that you are looking for

Comment: You are welcome. I'm just not sure if this code has high performance... Also, using blur in FMX Mobile applications is not very performatic... actually using any FMX Effects in Mobile Applications is not very good in terms of performance

Comment: I found that whole FMX is not to good in terms of performance :)

Comment: I liked the idea. I created a superclass and implemented subclasses with different effect filters.

Comment: I'll share it probably before it is ready. ;-) Looking at how to cache the bitmap intelligently.

Answer (score 2):

I created a TFrostGlass component which can also:

- cache
- have a background color tint
- rounded corners
- borders

You can see/download it here: https://github.com/Spelt/Frost-Glass